# Powershell loop to check the value of a parameter

Tags: powershell

I have a Ps code below which I am trying to adapt for a specific scenario, its an asynchronous API REST call, which gets called and could take some time to complete, the call returns a status which I have stored in the variable called outcome for explanation purposes. If the code below is executed, it will only run once which is fine, is there a way to make it continously check for the outcome of the Async rest call, I have hard coded this to "InProgress", how can I write the code such that in 5 minutes time, the value of outcome will now be "Succeeded", in this time the loop will need to constantly check until we have either Succeeded, Failed or cancelled.

```
#$outcome = "InProgress"
$outcome = "Failed"
while ($outcome){
    if ($outcome -eq "Succeeded"){
        Write-Output "The job ran successfully"
        break
    }elseif ($outcome -eq "Cancelled"){
        Write-Output "The job was cancelled"
        exit 1
    }elseif ($outcome -eq "Failed"){
        Write-Output "The job Failed"
        exit 1
    } else{
        write-output "The job is still running"   
    }
}
```

Comment: use `Start-Sleep` to insert a delay. change your `while` to test for `$Finished -eq $True`, set that var to `$False` before the `while`, and set it to `$True` in the `while` loop when one of your test conditions is met.

Comment: '*... its an asynchronous API REST cal*", how do you initiate this? (or how do you initiate your asynchronous script?). Or is this actually the question knowing that cmdlets like [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod) or something like [`Start-Proces`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) have parameters and handles to deal with this...

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use a <do until time meets 5 mins> if greater than 5 mins then set $outcome to "Succeeded"

```
    $timeout = New-TimeSpan -Minutes 5
$stpwatch = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
do {

 # add your code here that sets $outcome

} until ( ($outcome -eq "Succeeded") -or ($outcome -eq "Cancelled") -or ($outcome -eq "Failed") -or ($stpwatch.elapsed -lt $timeout))

if ($stpwatch.elapsed -gt $timeout)
{$outcome -eq "Succeeded"}
```

Hope this helps you out.